# NumberFormat returning wrong format for converting number to currency

Tags: javascript, formatting

Code:

```js
let currency = 400023;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
}).format(currency));
```

**Expected:**
€400.023,00

**Actual:**
€400,023.00

On the examples I found in the JS documentation, it shows dots being used as thousand separators and commas for cents, yet when I use it myself it doesn't work.

Comment: Firefox: "400.023,00 €", Chrome: "400.023,00 €", Safari: "400.023,00 €", Opera: "400.023,00 €". I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: If you run the JS file locally from your IDE?

Comment: If I run the code snippet here it work. But on my local machine it doesn't. 

It's also not working on a third party application I'm using which I assume hosts the running of the code on a server machine which also returns the same result with using commas instead of dots for thousand separators.

Comment: It may be that those implementations don't support the de language tag. That's one of the issues with the Intl object (and *toLocaleString*), also see [*Why does the JS Internationalization API for number formatting contradict German standards?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961284/why-does-the-js-internationalization-api-for-number-formatting-contradict-german).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @RobG pointed out it's an issue with your JS implementation, which isn't supporting the Intl object properly.

All current browsers have full support for Intl.

If you running your code on Node.js the situation is a little bit more complicated. Before Node.js 13, there was only partial support for internationalization (ICU) including Intl.

Starting with Node.js 13 there is full ICU/internationalization support built in by default. For details see:

- https://medium.com/@nodejs/node-js-12-to-lts-and-node-js-13-is-here-e28d6a4a2bd
- https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_embed_the_entire_icu_full_icu

Essentialy, you can run this piece of code:

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es',{month:'long'}).format(new Date(9E8)));
```

Your output might be:

- Error: No support for ICU - very old browser / Node.js
- January: Partial support for ICU - old browser / Node.js < 13
- enero: Full support for ICU - recent browser / Node.js >= 13

In case your stuck with Node.js < 13, you can backfill full ICU support with https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu.